# Count number of files and print the last file

Tags: bash

I am missing some episodes of the TV series friends, and I would like to know how many files I am missing per season. I would like to print out the last episode of each season and the number of files for each season.

The files have the format:

```
Friends S01E01 The Pilot.mkv
Friends S10E11 The One Where the Stripper Cries.mkv
```

Comment: Before down voting remember that it is ok to answer your own question ["if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following bash script/oneliner should give you what you need, with details because it might help if you have the last episode of a season but earlier episodes are missing:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
ls Friends* | cut -c10-14 | \
  awk -F'E' '{arr[$1]=arr[$1]" "$2; num[$1]++;} END { for (i in arr) printf "Season %s (%2d files) : %s\n", i, num[i], arr[i] }' | \
  sort
```

Using awk, arrays with index being the number of the season are incremented to count the number of episodes, and also print the list of episode numbers so you can easily see which ones are missing. I used cut with columns 10 to 14 because in this case, we can safely assume that the numbers are where we want them.

The output is as follows:

```
Season 01 ( 9 files) :  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
Season 02 (10 files) :  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
Season 03 (10 files) :  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
Season 04 (10 files) :  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
Season 05 ( 9 files) :  01 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
Season 06 (10 files) :  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
Season 07 (10 files) :  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
Season 08 (10 files) :  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
Season 09 (10 files) :  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
Season 10 ( 7 files) :  01 02 03 04 05 06 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The following bash scipt will work:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {01..10}
do
   ls Friends\ S$i* | tail -n 1
   ls Friends\ S$i* | wc -l
   printf "\n"
done
```

It will produce results as follows:

```
Friends S01E24 The One Where Rachel Finds Out.mkv
24

Friends S02E24 The One with Barry and Mindy's Wedding.mkv
24
```